# How many combinations of clothes, if you only require one piece of clothing?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say I have 4 jackets, 3 pants, 2 shirts, **but you're only required to wear 1 piece of clothing,** as in you can either wear 1 jacket and nothing else, or wear 1 jacket, 1 pants and nothing else, or wear 1 jacket, 1 pants, or 1 shirt. So, if there was only 1 jacket, 1 pants, and 1 shirt, you would have 7 different combinations.

What would be the general solution for this problem?

I was simply overthinking it and the hints provided helped a lot. If you just consider not wearing a piece of clothing as just another option, the answer for the example above is : 
(5 x 4 x 3) - 1 (-1 combination because you're required to wear at least one piece of clothing).

Comment: You actually have 7 combinations, not 6.  Hint: consider "no jacket" as an extra kind of jacket and so on, making sure that you're then not counting not wearing any clothes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. We can wear no jacket or one of the $4$ given jackets: so we have $1+4=5$ options. Similarly for pants and shirts.

So what is the solution for this problem?

P.S. If we have only 1 jacket, 1 pants, and 1 shirt, then the triple $(j,p,s)$ could be
$$(1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1),\\ (1,0,0), (0,1,0),
(0,0,1), (0,0,0)$$
which are $2\cdot2\cdot 2=8$ ways, or $8-1=7$ ways if not wearing any clothes is not allowed.